# What are the best plants to cultivate yeast from?

Tags: yeast

I know that cultivating yeast from potatoes yields a good brewing yeast and that forms of wheat make good baking yeast, however; I have not seen much information on other useful plant yeast cultures. What are some of the other plants that offer potentially useful yeast cultures?

*edit : corrected my error in thinking yeast was produced by plants due to a answer given

Comment: Are the wine-producing yeasts that live on grapes too obvious?  (FWIW, the plants do not produce the yeast.  Yeasts are independent organisms which colonize the surface of some plants, among many other things.  But they, and other fermentation-producing organisms, can be found elsewhere.  See for instance sourdough bread.)

Comment: Grapes are a bit obvious but it follows the main idea of my question. I'm curious about plants that are not commonly used. There isn't a directory that I could find that lists yeast cells commonly fond on specific types of flora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeast colonize the surface of many plants — for example they are a typical part of the normal surface flora (microbiome) of fruits such as grapes<sup>1</sup> and pears<sup>2</sup>.

As you can see from the second reference, yeast can compete with other microorganisms to delay rotting of the fruit.

You might also find the ["Uses" section of the wikipedia article on yeast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeast#Uses) and [this article on winemaking](https://daily.sevenfifty.com/the-science-of-winemaking-yeasts/) to be of interest.

References:

1: [Zahavi, T., Droby, S., Cohen, L., Weiss, B., & Ben-Arie, R. (2002). Characterization of the yeast flora on the surface of grape berries in Israel. VITIS-GEILWEILERHOF-, 41(4), 203-208.](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3875/bc73a1626c670cd5148ac05567ca28b415ee.pdf)

2: [Benbow, J. M., & Sugar, D. (1999). Fruit surface colonization and biological control of postharvest diseases of pear by preharvest yeast applications. Plant Disease, 83(9), 839-844.](https://apsjournals.apsnet.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1094/PDIS.1999.83.9.839)